# PrimeFaces p:chart tag not updating

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have used `<p:chart>` tag in outputpanel. What I want to do is when user clicks next (p:command link), new data is loaded and chart gets updated. but when I do it, only legend updated if new series is added and the marker and line do not shows for new data. I tried to update via widgetvar as well as by id.
my Tag is:

```
<h:form id="frmSensorGraphPage">
 <p:outputPanel id="sensorChartPanel">
    <p:chart id="sensorChart" widgetVar="sensorChartVar" type="line"      model="#{assetgroup.sensorModel}"/>
 </p:outputPanel>
 </form>
```

I tried updating by frmSensorGraphPage:sensorChartPanel as well as frmSensorGraphPage:sensorChart